# Android OpengGL 1.0 Displaying two textured planes issue

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, mesh

I have an interesting problem with displaying two or quads at the same time while displaying one is working fine.
I was able to implement this popular tutorial for displaying a simple quad with texture:
http://www.jayway.com/2010/02/15/opengl-es-tutorial-for-android-part-v/

So basically i have a class named SimplePlane that extends Mesh class exactly as in tutorial.
I create an instance of SimplePlane:

```
    public void onSurfaceCreated(...){
    plane1 = new SimplePane(1,1);
    plane2 = new SimplePane(1,1);
    plane1.z = 2.0f
    plane2.z = 3.0f
    }
```

and then I draw mesh:

```
public void draw(GL10 gl) {
//set all gl variables as usual for opengl
plane1.draw(gl); // is displayed properly
plane2.draw(gl); //for some reason is not visible even that its behind plane1 and bigger to make sure plane1 is not covering plane2
}
```

The problem is only the first plane1 is being displayed.
If in my code i place plane2 first then plane 2 is diplayed and plane1 is not.
Mind you its not the z position issue as i ruled it out by creating one larger and semi transparent. And if i comment one out then the other is visible.
I added logging and both plane's draw methods are being called but only one is visible.

Am I allowed to take this approach calling one draw(gl) after another or i have to create a group object as in tutorial?

Comment: Have you tried changing the drawing order (So first two, then one)? You say you tried making one semitransparent, but please keep in mind that transparency is kind of a problem with depth testing.

Comment: Hi Yes i did try changing order, so then plane number two is displayed only if its first.

Comment: Have you tried changing the x or y value instead of the z (So the plane would appear next to the other one instead of behind), to rule out any depth buffer problems? Also, Could you post the entire body of your `Plane.draw()` function?

Comment: I tried making one smaller and larger and the other way...and checked their positions when visible to confirm they dont occupy the same place on screen(tried plane1 as first and then tried again plane2 as first). The code is to lonf to post it here but its taken from the tuorial here: http://www.jayway.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/Tutorial_Part_VI.zip